# How to capture all regex groups in one regex?

Tags: python, regex, string, delimiter, regex-group

Given a file like this:

```
# For more information about CC-CEDICT see:
# http://cc-cedict.org/wiki/
A A [A] /(slang) (Tw) to steal/
AA制 AA制 [A A zhi4] /to split the bill/to go Dutch/
AB制 AB制 [A B zhi4] /to split the bill (where the male counterpart foots the larger portion of the sum)/(theater) a system where two actors take turns in acting the main role, with one actor replacing the other if either is unavailable/
A咖 A咖 [A ka1] /class "A"/top grade/
A圈兒 A圈儿 [A quan1 r5] /at symbol, @/
A片 A片 [A pian4] /adult movie/pornography/
```

I want to build a json object that:

- skip lines that starts with `#`
- breaks lines into 4 parts

  1. tradition character (spans from start `^` until the next space)
  2. simplified character (spans from the first space to the second)
  3. pinyin (spans between the square brackets `[...]`)
  4. the gloss space between the first `/` till the last  `/` (note there are cases where there can be slashes within the gloss, e.g. `/adult movie/pornography/`

I am currently doing it as such:

```
>>> for line in text.split('\n'):
...     if line.startswith('#'): continue;
...     line = line.strip()
...     simple, _, line = line.partition(' ')
...     trad, _, line = line.partition(' ')
...     print simple, trad
... 
A A
AA制 AA制
AB制 AB制
A咖 A咖
A圈兒 A圈儿
A片 A片
```

To get the `[...]`, I had to do:

```
>>> import re
>>> line = "A片 A片 [A pian4] /adult movie/pornography/"
>>> simple, _, line = line.partition(' ')
>>> trad, _, line = line.partition(' ')
>>> re.findall(r'\[.*\]', line)[0].strip('[]')
'A pian4'
```

And to find the `/.../`, I had to do:

```
>>> line = "A片 A片 [A pian4] /adult movie/pornography/"
>>> re.findall(r'\/.*\/$', line)[0].strip('/')
'adult movie/pornography'
```

**How do I use regex groups to catch all of them at once which doing multiple partitions/splits/findall?**

Comment: i am late to party..so i will put it as comment :- https://regex101.com/r/uO0yS1/1

Comment: Thank you all for the great answers!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I could extract the info using regular expressions instead. This way, you can catch blocks in groups and then handle them as desired:

```
import re

with open("myfile") as f:
    data = f.read().split('\n')
    for line in data:
        if line.startswith('#'): continue
        m = re.search(r"^([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) \[([^]]*)\] \/(.*)\/$", line)
        if m:
            print(m.groups())
```

That is regular expression splits the string in the following groups:

```
^([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) \[([^]]*)\] \/(.*)\/$
  ^^^^^   ^^^^^     ^^^^^       ^^
   1)      2)        3)         4)
```

That is:

1. the first word.
2. the second word.
3. the text within `[` and `]`.
4. the text from `/` up to the `/` before the end of the line.

It returns:

```
('A', 'A', 'A', '(slang) (Tw) to steal')
('AA制', 'AA制', 'A A zhi4', 'to split the bill/to go Dutch')
('AB制', 'AB制', 'A B zhi4', 'to split the bill (where the male counterpart foots the larger portion of the sum)/(theater) a system where two actors take turns in acting the main role, with one actor replacing the other if either is unavailable')
('A咖', 'A咖', 'A ka1', 'class "A"/top grade')
('A圈兒', 'A圈儿', 'A quan1 r5', 'at symbol, @')
('A片', 'A片', 'A pian4', 'adult movie/pornography')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
p = re.compile(ru"(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+\[([^\]]*)\]\s+/(.*)/$")
m = p.match(line)
if m:
    simple, trad, pinyin, gloss = m.groups()
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping for more details.

Comment: Or for brevity `simple, trad, pinyin, gloss = m.groups()`

Comment: Thanks, I don’t write Python on a regular basis, so I’m glad that my answer was useful at all. :)

Answer (score 2):

This might help:

```
preg = re.compile(r'^(?<!#)(\w+)\s(\w+)\s(\[.*?\])\s/(.+)/$',
                  re.MULTILINE | re.UNICODE)

with open('your_file') as f:
    for line in f:
        match = preg.match(line)
        if match:
            print(match.groups())
```

Take a look [here](https://regex101.com/r/xA3zB2/1) for a detailed explanation of the used regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

I created following regex to match all the four groups:

[REGEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uN4bK4/2)

`^(.*)\s(.*)\s(\[.*\])\s(\/.*\/)`

This does assume that there is only one space in between the groups however if you have more you can just add a modifier.

Here is a demo of how this works with python with the lines provided in the question:

[IDEONE DEMO](https://ideone.com/Z9jmGv)

Comment: I assume it would be a good learning for everyone if downvoters also leave relevant comments.